# Model and controller design approach for polymorphic assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

Below I have outlined the structure of a polymorphic association.

In VacationsController I put some comments inline describing my current issue. However, I wanted to post this to see if my whole approach here is a little off. You can see in business_vacations_controller and staff_vacations_controller that I've had to make 'getters' for the model and controller so that I can access them from within vacations_model so I know which type of object I'm dealing with. Although it works, it's starting to feel a little questionable.

Is there a better 'best practice' for what I'm trying to accomplish?

## models

vacation.rb

```
 class Vacation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :vacationable, :polymorphic => true
 end
```

business.rb

```
 class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :vacations, :as => :vacationable
 end
```

staff.rb

```
 class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :vacations, :as => :vacationable
 end
```

business_vacation.rb

```
 class BusinessVacation < Vacation
 end
```

staff_vacation.rb

```
 class StaffVacation < Vacation
 end
```

## controllers

business_vacations_controller.rb

```
 class BusinessVacationsController < VacationsController

   private
  
     def controller_str
       "business_schedules"
     end
  
     def my_model
       BusinessVacation
     end
  
     def my_model_str
       "business_vacation"
     end
  
 end
```

staff_vacations_controller.rb

```
 class StaffVacationsController < VacationsController

   private
  
     def controller_str
       "staff_schedules"
     end
  
     def my_model
       StaffVacation
     end
  
     def my_model_str
       "staff_vacation"
     end

 end
```

vacations_controller.rb

```
 class VacationsController < ApplicationController

   def create
     # Build the vacation object with either an instance of BusinessVacation or StaffVacation

     vacation = @class.new(params[my_model_str])

     # Now here's the current issue -- I want to save the object on the association. So if it's a 'BusinessVacation' object I want to save something like:
  
     business = Business.find(vacation.vacationable_id)
     business.vacations.build
     business.save
  
     # But if it's a 'StaffVacation' object I want to save something like:
  
     staff = Staff.find(vacation.vacationable_id)
     staff.vacations.build
     staff.save
   
     # I could do an 'if' statement, but I don't really like that idea. Is there a better way?

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to :controller => controller_str, :action => "index", :id => vacation.vacationable_id }
     end
 
   end
 
   private
     def select_class
       @class = Kernel.const_get(params[:class])
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a lot of hoops to jump through in the VacationsController to make it aware of the context. Is there a reason that the StaffVacationsController and BusinessVacationsController couldn't each have a #create action and the views would submit to whichever is appropriate? These actions would already know the model context and be able to redirect to the appropriate url afterward.

Comment: Yes, maybe that's the best solution. There's a lot of shared code that's not shown, that's why I had it in the same controller, but maybe it's to the point where I should explore separating them out.

Comment: I was wondering if there may be some shared code motivating that... a bit tough to call without the details, but maybe some of the shared logic would go into the Vacation model and/or a module that's included in the controllers?